# How to manage dynamic entities on mysql / hibernate / java combination

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create some dynamic entities through an interface where there is a master entity that can be customized by end users. Many variations of such entity can exist on the db and application at the same time.

I need to define such dynamic entity on db / store data in them (through forms that are customized to collect data for them. and use such data in our app.

The ui part is not daunting for us and we have a nice way of dealing with them. But managing large varieties of a single entity seems to be the problem.

Hibernate needs a pojo. We are currently looking into map based serialization with hibernate.

The issue here is - is it a good practice to create a separate table for each variation of the entity ? or is it better to denormalize the entities entirely and store them as key / value pairs in strings with a type id and then convert ?

Is there a better solution then these ?

We are also thinking of evaluating cloud db's if they fit the scenario better. Any pointers are highly welcome.

Comment: Clarification - Since the entities will be defined / customized through an ui we cannot use pojo's. The real challenge for us is to identify the best approach to store the entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since I asked this question and in the mean time I have been experimenting heavily with my options.

One option I tried is to use hibernate map mode and though its quite flexible to define and alter entities I couldn't actually store varieties of a particular family. We achieved some success with storing varieties by creating a key value store within MySQL and wrote a library to do data conversion. However querying this data on mysql effectively looked daunting. We got by with it by using our search indexes on lucene as an answer.

However a conclusion in mycase is to use HBase and do intelligent scan queries. That's my answer to this problem for now and it seems to work well.